# Need help identifying this manga- large guy helps out schoolgirl

Tags: ore-monogatari

I remember reading a fairly new manga a while back where the main protagonist is a large guy on the wrestling team, who is actually really sweet and doesn't like to see girls get hurt. He rescues a girl from being groped on the subway (I'm pretty sure this is what happened), and she bakes him cookies and wants to be friends. He likes her, but assumes she actually is interested in his popular friend (who always rejects girls) and keeps inviting him along when she asks to hang out. It seems like the girl actually did like the main guy and not the good-looking friend, but he doesn't realize.

Does anyone know what this manga is called? Did it get cancelled?

Comment: It is probably ore monogatari, I'll add it as an answer with references when I can.

Answer (score 5):

The title you're looking for is probably Ore Monogatari. Your description of the story is quite close to the synopsis of the manga, with both the big guy premise and the popular friend.

From [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/manga/36933/Ore_Monogatari!!)

> Tsuyoshi Takeo is a freshman in high school. (Both estimates) Weight: 120kg, Height: 2 meters. He spends his days peacefully with his super-popular-with-girls, yet insensitive childhood friend, Sunagawa. One morning, on the train to school, Takeo saves a girl, Yamato, from being molested by a pervert. Could this be the beginning of spring for Takeo?

[image: Cover of Vol. 2]

### References

- [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/manga/36933/Ore_Monogatari!!)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Love_Story!!)